# How do I correctly sort this array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Im trying to sort through an array of stacked cubes.
The Array looks like this(an example)

```
Nth Cube | Position (0, its on the desk, >0,  its on another cube)
---
1|6
---
2|8
---
3|0
---
4|0
---
5|0
---
6|0
---
7|1
---
8|4
---
```

which would look like this visualized

```
[7] [2]
---
[1] [8]
---
[6] [4] [3] [5]
---
```

I sorted out the cubes that are on another one:

**string[,] t in this case is the entire Array**

```
static string[,] stackedCubes(string[,] t)
    {
        string[,] stackedHelp = new string[NumberOfStacked(),2];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < t.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (t[i, 1]!="0")
            {

                stackedHelp[j, 0] = t[i, 0];
                stackedHelp[j, 1] = t[i, 1];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return stackedHelp;
    }
```

which comes out as :

```
1|6
---
2|8
---
7|1
---
8|4
---
```

now im trying to put them down from the top(so 7/2 then 1/8)

**string[,] t from here on is stackedCubes**

```
static string[,] Putdown(string[,] t)
    {
        string[,] stackedOrder = new string[NumberOfStacked(), 2];
        int j = 0;
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < t.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (t[i, 1] == t[j, 0])
                {
                    j = i;
                }
                else if(IsSomethingOnTheCube(t[j,0],t)==false)
                {
                    stackedOrder[i, 0] = t[j, 0];
                    stackedOrder[i, 1] = "0";
                    t[i, 1] = "0";
                }
            }
        }
        while (AreAllTheCubesOnTable(t) != true);

        return stackedOrder;
    }
```

here im going from the first Cube 1(t[j,0]) and check if there is something on it, it finds it on t[i,1] and gives back the 7(t[j,0]) and goes back.
I check if there is something on the Cube here

```
    static bool IsSomethingOnTheCube(string Cube,string[,] t)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if(Cube==t[i,1])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I also check whether or not are they all on the desk (with the do-while)

```
    static bool AreAllTheCubesOnTable(string[,] t)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (t[i, 1] != "0")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And the output is all wrong:

```
7|0
---
7|0
---
7|0
---
7|0
---
```

when it should be something like:

```
7|0
---
1|0
---
2|0
---
8|0
---
```

Where am I indexing wrong?(or something else)

Comment: What is your expected result (7|0, 1|0, 2|0, 8|0) supposed to represent?

Comment: the returning value of Putdown() - which is string[,] stackedOrder - when its all done

Comment: Your use of domain language in the question is confusing; a "cube" being "on a desk" or "on another cube" means absolutely nothing to people outside your brain or outside those in the know. Speak in plain code.

Comment: @eurotrash While this might be your opinion, I just visualized a pyramid consisting of cubes. So while you might deem it useless, OPs description helped me to put his problem into context

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what this is supposed to do either.

Comment: where I put them in the brackets, thats how you should visualize, cant really explain better

Comment: Is the purpose of the code to sort the input into a 2d array that represents the sorted virtualisation?

Answer (score 0):

In the sample provided

```
string[] cubes = new string[]
  {"1|6", "2|8", "3|0", "4|0", "5|0", "6|0", "7|1", "8|4"};
```

The bottom line in the question looks like random one. Let's order the
lowest cubes (say, lexicographically) and so the visualization will be:

```
lines:
   2:        [2]     [7]
   1:        [8]     [1]
   0:    [3] [4] [5] [6]  <- bottom line is sorted
------------------------
files:    0   1   2   3
```

Having done this, we can implement two *help methods*:

```
   // Line: 0 for lowest cubes
   private static int CubeLine(string value, IEnumerable<String> stack) {
      for (int line = 0; ; ++line) {
        string parent = value.Substring(value.IndexOf('|') + 1);

        if ("0".Equals(parent))
          return line;

        value = stack.First(item => item.StartsWith(parent + "|"));
      }
    }
```

And

```
    // File: 0 for leftmost cubes
    private static int CubeFile(string value, IEnumerable<String> stack) {
      string root = value;

      while (true) {
        string parent = root.Substring(root.IndexOf('|') + 1);

        if ("0".Equals(parent))
          break;

        root = stack.First(item => item.StartsWith(parent + "|"));
      }

      return stack
        .Where(item => item.Substring(value.IndexOf('|') + 1) == "0")
        .OrderBy(item => item)
        .Select((item, index) => new {
          item = item,
          index = index
        })
        .First(item => item.item == root)
        .index;
    }
```

And then you can easily sort whatever you like. For instance, let's sort
topmost cubes first, in case of tie leftmost first:

```
 string[] cubes = new string[]
   {"1|6", "2|8", "3|0", "4|0", "5|0", "6|0", "7|1", "8|4"};

  var result = cubes
    .Select (cube => new {
      name = cube.Substring(0, cube.IndexOf('|')),
      file = CubeFile(cube, cubes),
      line = CubeLine(cube, cubes) })
    .OrderByDescending(cube => cube.line)
    .ThenBy(cube => cube.file)
    .Select(cube => cube.name);

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Outcome is

```
  2, 7, 8, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

**Edit**: if you want to sort left to right first, top to bottom on tie:

```
  var result = cubes
    .Select (cube => new {
      name = cube.Substring(0, cube.IndexOf('|')),
      file = CubeFile(cube, cubes),
      line = CubeLine(cube, cubes) })
    .OrderBy(cube => cube.file)
    .ThenByDescending(cube => cube.line)
    .Select(cube => cube.name);
```

And the outcome is

```
 3, 2, 8, 4, 5, 7, 1, 6
```

**Edit 2**: Put down order: bottom first, ties arbitrary

```
  var result = cubes
    .Select (cube => new {
      name = cube.Substring(0, cube.IndexOf('|')),
      file = CubeFile(cube, cubes),
      line = CubeLine(cube, cubes) })
    .OrderBy(cube => cube.line)
    .Select(cube => cube.name);
```

Outcome:

```
  3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 2, 7
```

Comment: The expected result in the question gives ordering 7 -> 1 which gives the visualisation implies vertical ordering. Your answer gives an horizontal ordering.

Comment: @EpicSam: having `CubeFile` and `CubeLine` one can easily sort out the array as required. See my edit.

Comment: oh boy where do i start, first thank you for taking time anwsering the question, however since i am only started learning programming recently i cant really make anything of the code you put there, and translate to mine succesfuly(i tried, when it could build it output system.linq ...), also i really only need help with the sorted array stackedCubes() when I try to Putdown() them from up, like shown in the expected results

Answer (score 0):

Although multidimensional arrays are used in numerous examples when starting programming, using an array of a strongly typed classes is generally advisable. That said, when the multidimensional array can still be parsed to another format, such as a dictionary. For example:

```
string[,] cubes = {{"1","6"} ,{ "2","8"} ,{ "3","0"} ,{ "4","0"} ,{ "5","0"} ,{ "6","0"} ,{ "7","1"} ,{ "8","4"}};


//create a dictionary of all cube-parents
var parents = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, cubes.GetLength(0))                    
                group cubes[i,0] by cubes[i,1])
                .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.ToArray());    

var layer = parents["0"]; //table level cubes [3,4,5,6]
var layers=  new List<string[]>();
while(layer != null){
    layers.Add(layer);
    string[] children, nextlayer = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < layer.Length; i++)
        if(layer[i] != null && parents.TryGetValue(layer[i], out children)){
            if(nextlayer==null)nextlayer= new string[layer.Length];
            nextlayer[i] = children[0]; //what to do with multiple children?
        }
    layer= nextlayer;
};
```

When the above is finished, `layers` contains `{[3,4,5,6],[null,8,null,1], [null,2,null,7]}` In other words the several layers. I'm not entirely sure which is the desired end result. Is it the visual representation or something like all cubes not on the table (for the latter it would simply be all items which do not have parent '0')